# Cant find certificate file in app_data

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services

I'm generating a JWT and I am using a p12 certificate file to sign it. This code works locally but deployed on AWS i get the following exception message: "The system cannot find the file specified".

Here's the code:

```
// Gets the projects path to App_Data/privatekey.p12
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString(), "privatekey.p12");


X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();

// Throws System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified
cert.Import(path, "SECRET PASSWORD HERE", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable); 

RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
```

I've placed the 'privatekey.p12' file in the projects App_Data folder and included it, I've also set "Items to deploy" to "All files in this project" and I'm still getting the error.

The file is found using Directory.GetFiles("App_Data path here") both locally and using aws so I'm sure it's actually there.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are 3 possible causes of that error:

1. Problems with path. Missing slashes, misspelled names of folders or file.
2. Security issue, when user under which app pool is running have no permissions to read( or write) to the specified location.
3. Take error at face value and make sure it DOES present at the location you are expecting it to be. Basically go to the server and check, if file has been copied there. Strangest thing did happen.:)

Comment: Thanks for your response.

1: I'm almost 100% certain that the file name is correctly spelled since it's working locally.
2: This might be the case, how would I grant admin permissions to the application on aws to make sure?
3: The file is found using Directory.GetFiles("App_Data path here") both locally and using aws

Comment: @lins Another thing comes to mind is "Load User Profile" setting has been set to true on application pool. Without it cryptographic subsystem wouldn't work.